# How to make Recycle Bin in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, recycle-bin

i want to create a `Recycle Bin` in my web project, i use a Details View with EDIT and DELETE option to present and edit data from database and its worked perfectly but want a Recycle Bin for `Deleted Data` and if Owner wants to delete completely Delete from Recycle .
if u have some codes or  idea or some links help me please !

Comment: Add a "deleted" column to your table(s).

Comment: you can make something like soft delete http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall have a field in db which means isDeteled or isRecycled and when it is set to 1 show it in recycleBin/ if user finally deletes record delete if from db.

Better choice is to have status field for enum Active/Archived/Deleted or Active/Archived/Deleted/Purged

when the record in last state of this enum delete it in real time, or by SQL clean-up job or something like this.

Comment: Thank you @Vladmir, can i just add 1 bool column isDeleted and in a page like ( Recycle ) showing all data with the isDeleted = true value and there use Delete Command !?

Comment: You need to implement logic that will delete entries from db in your Delete command. Just show all deleted data in grid, check necessary items, and execute deletion for them